# D3 forceCollide not working properly after updating the underlying data

Tags: d3.js

I've been trying to learn d3 by reading some tutorials and decided to build a bubble chart that includes d3-force for collision and dragging and dynamically updating of the underlying data

Basically what I am trying to achieve is that I change the value property of 'a' every one second by incrementing it, and expect that the bubble for 'a' increases and pushes the other bubbles around it

```
const circles = this.svg.selectAll('circle').data(this.state.data);
const node = circles
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .call(d3.drag()
           .on('start', dragstarted)
           .on('drag', dragged)
           .on('end', dragended))
      .on('mouseover', d => {
        tooltip.html(d.name + ' ' + d.value);
        return tooltip.style('visibility', 'visible')
      })
      .on('mouseout', () => tooltip.style('visibility', 'hidden'));

      node.append('circle')
        .attr('r', d => d.value)
        .style('fill', 'limegreen');

      node.append('text')
        .text(d => d.name);
```

My full attempt is here: https://codepen.io/luanped/pen/rojged?editors=0010

When you run it you can see that the first 4 seconds or so it's almost correct, 'a' increments and pushes other bubbles around (however hovering over the bubble, the lower left tooltip will continue displaying the initial value, rather than the newly updated value)

I am guessing that somehow I am not doing the transition of the inner element (circle inside g) correctly - in the sense that although I have animated the radius drawn, the underlying data model still think's it's the original value? Hence the collision boundary and the wrong tooltip

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: why do you have 10 tooltip divs and 10 force simulations?

Comment: That certainly doesn't sound like what I want, I'd expected 1 tooltip div to be reused and 1 simulation

Comment: I tested by running only the simulation and the creation of the tooltip div on the first call to drawChart() but the end result didn't change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues from what I can see:

1. The simulation is decaying too fast.
2. You aren't updating the first item in the data array - you are replacing it.

For one, the easiest solution is to chose a lower alpha decay rate than the default, which off memory is something like 0.0228. Your simulation is decaying to fast: it cools down before you are done updating the number, try a lower value:

```
 .alphaDecay(0.001);
```

For two, the issue is a bit more subtle. But, if you use `console.log(newData)`, you can see that the first node isn't been assigned a `x`,`y`,`vx`, or `vy` properties like the other items in the data array:

[image]

This is because the new data isn't part of the force layout. And, while you are updating the bound data on the SVG circles and text:

```
const circles = this.svg.selectAll('circle').data(this.state.data);
const labels = this.svg.selectAll('text').data(this.state.data);
...
circles.transition(t).attr('r', d => d.value);
labels.transition(t).text(d => d.name + ' ' + d.value);
```

You aren't updating the data on the `g` that the mouse over event is set for, so it never changes.

We can update the data on the parent `g`s, `circle`s, `text`s, and the force layout in one go, we can do this by updating the first object in the data array rather than creating a new object:

```
Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .take(10)
  .subscribe(() => {
    const newData = this.state.data;
    newData[0].value += 10;
    this.setState({ data: newData });
  });
```

This works because when binding data to a selection or assigning nodes to a force layout, both selection and force layout will use references to the objects in the data array (not a reference to the data array itself). If you update a object in the data array, you update the nodes of the force layout and the data bound to the selection (which is commonly seen in d3-force examples where tick function's don't update the data with `.data()` before repositioning the elements). But if you replace an object in the data array you aren't updating the reference in the force layout or the selection to the new data item. You could use `simulation.nodes()` to update the nodes of the force, but you'd want to carry over the `vx`, `vy`, `x`, and `y` attributes (otherwise they will default to new values).

Here's an [updated pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bOYgJp?editors=0010).

As for other options, you could also restart the simulation each draw - this would allow you to leave the alpha decay at its default.

*Of course, you also don't want to create extra force layouts/tooltips, as noted in the comments*

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help - works perfectly like this. I did initially also try mutating the data rather than replacing it - however I was never aware before about the alphaDecay, which meant that the simulation still behaved weirdly. With alphaDecay it fixes it. I will also read more into simulation.nodes() as mutating the data is not something I would prefer doing if I can avoid it :) But thanks again

Comment: Hi again, sorry just checked out the updated pen, initially looked alright however after letting the simulation run for about 10 mins or so, they all break again, see image: https://ibb.co/nsKLJGj -- I assume 0.001 alphaDecay slowed down the simulation, i'll try setting the alphaDecay to 0 and see what happens; (from the docs: o have the simulation run forever at the current alpha, set the decay rate to zero)

Comment: It could be the alpha - especially if you are adjusting the radii after 10 minutes, if you are updating the force you could reheat it by setting alpha itself higher each update instead of reducing alpha decay.